# Allow access from specific url and block access by ip on admin folder

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess

I have a php file from the front end that needs to trigger a php file from the admin back-end but it can't do that because i added in .htaccess:

```
ErrorDocument 403 "Forbidden
order allow,deny
allow from 182.112.0.1/13
allow from 76.112.0.1/13 ....
```

And it echo's in the interior of the php file a forbidden error.
Is there anyway to overcome this with htaccess file?

something like

```
ErrorDocument 403 "Forbidden
order allow,deny
allow from 182.112.0.1/13
allow from 76.112.0.1/13 ....
allow from file.php // this doesn't work
```

Comment: Is this admin back-end file being **linked** from the content of the front end, or is it being **included** directly in php?

Comment: In the php file from the front end i have include($GLOBALS['admin_folder']."/config.inc.php"); and in the tpl file (template i have href="{admin}/file.php" So i believe that is both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`mod_setenvif`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_setenvif.html).

So something like this should work:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "file\.php" ALLOWED_PHP

ErrorDocument 403 "Forbidden
order allow,deny
allow from 182.112.0.1/13
allow from 76.112.0.1/13
allow from env=ALLOWED_PHP
```

Comment: That did the job, now if i have multiple files i just add them like this: SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "file\.php" ALLOWED_PHP SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "file\.php" ALLOWED_PHP SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "file\.php" ALLOWED_PHP

Comment: yes or you can use same line with `OR` e.g. **`SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "(file|foo|bar)\.php" ALLOWED_PHP`**

Comment: you could do something like `"^admin_folder/(.*)"`